# Read the cells of excel with valid numbers in openpyxl

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I'm parsing some Excel files via python - openpyxl library.

My objective is to read the cells placed under a certain word or letter like N.
So once N is found, the code should move to the cell underneath and if it contains a valid number, put it in a list otherwise break reading.
I am having problem with defining the right condition.

```
for col_cells in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2):

        for cell in col_cells:

            if cell.value == "N":

                print (cell)

               

                print ("N is Found")

                break

 

N=[]; i=1; celln=cell    

while celln.value =! 0:

    cellb=cell.row + i

    Nlist. append(sheet[cell.column+str(cellb)].value) 

    i=i+1

    print(i)

    celln=sheet[cell.column+str(cellb)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to break the whole loop, every `cell` object has its coordinates in it so you can use those to grab the next cell in turn. For example:

```
some_list = []

for col_cells in sheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2):
    for cell in col_cells:
        if cell.value == "N":
            try:
                some_list.append(int(sheet['{}{}'.format(cell.column, cell.row+1)].value))

            except ValueError:
                continue
```

instead of checking if its a valid number just try and change it to an `int` and catch an exception if it fails. Remember that in Python "its Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" ([EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)).